# python replace not working

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to do multiple replaces in python but the replace is not working, it only replaces the `<UNK>` but not `</s>`.
Can anybody tell me where the error is?

```
text=text.replace(":<UNK>","")
text=text.replace("</s>","")
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the text?

Comment: 1.595879e-04(Kan) 7.098440e-08(Şekerini:<UNK>) 2.558586e-06(Etkileyen) 7.671361e-07(Besinler) 3.731427e-02(</s>)  (ailehekimligi-0000000001)  I have a lot of sentences like this. I just want to delete <UNK> and </s>

Comment: What Python version? Works fine for me on Py3.4.

Comment: Does `text = '1.595879e-04(Kan) 7.098440e-08(Şekerini:<UNK>) 2.558586e-06(Etkileyen) 7.671361e-07(Besinler) 3.731427e-02(</s>) (ailehekimligi-0000000001)'.replace(':<UNK>', '').replace('</s>', ''); print(text)` work for you?

Comment: [Works fine for me too](https://repl.it/C5jA/0)

Comment: Works for me too. 2.7.10

Comment: I have python 2.7.6... I

Comment: can you share the Traceback please? @oezlem

Comment: I dont have any errors i just have the new lines like this: Doğum sırasında dayanılanabileceğinizden fazla ağrıyla karşı karşıya kaldığınızda ağrı giderme yöntemlerine başvurulmasını talep etmekten çekinmeyin. </s>
I´m also running a code to get just the text between the parentheses.

Comment: Please show us the complete example. The text in your comment doesn't represent the string previously given.

Comment: Worked for me as well with both strings of text. Python 2.7.3

Comment: Given the number of replies saying it works for them, I'm wondering if you're running into a localization issue? Without seeing the whole script, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ju5y8aKd here is the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code worked correctly but You can use regular expression to find and replace the text.

```
import re
text = '1.595879e-04(Kan) 7.098440e-08(Şekerini:<UNK>) 2.558586e-06(Etkileyen) 7.671361e-07(Besinler) 3.731427e-02(</s>) (ailehekimligi-0000000001)'
output = re.sub(r':<UNK>', '', text)
output = re.sub(r':</s>', '', text)
print(output)
```

also if you have unicode string, you can use `u''` before text and your replace statement.

Comment: I dont know why but none of it works for me, I keep having:
 Pınar Belendir </s>
 Sınırlı Sorumluluk Beyanı </s>
 ailem.com'un içeriği, kullanıcıyı bilgilendirmeye yönelik hazırlanmıştır. Sitede yer alan bilgiler, hiçbir zaman bir hekim tedavisinin ya da konsültasyonunun yerini alamaz. Bu kaynaktan yola çıkarak, ilaç tedavisine başlanması ya da mevcut ilaç tedavisinin değiştirilmesi kesinlikte tavsiye edilmez. ailem.com'un içeriği, asla kişisel teşhis ya da tedavi yönteminin seçimi için değerlendirilmemelidir. </s>
Even though I have the UNK deleted.

Comment: Probably not worth using regular expressions for a string literal here. @oezlem, please provide us with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ixgbAzCd This is the code I am using. I have two files, I want to compare each file extract the text for same lines, and delete UNK and </s>
here are the files:
http://pastebin.com/FVxk6e4v
http://pastebin.com/hk0KGMXY